# in YAML, how to assign a string to a key that has subkeys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

In YAML, for I18n Rails translations, I have

```
en:
  mainkey:
    subkey: 'Some Text'
```

I can retrieve en.mainkey.subkey, but how can I assign a text to en.mainkey !?

Comment: because 
`en:`  

  `mainkey: 'Main Text'`  

    `subkey: 'Some Text`  


doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The value of `en.mainkey` is the hash containing `subkey`. It can't also be a string. You can e.g. put it under another key next to subkey.

Comment: Gross.  Guess I have to add a subkey called "value" to any keys with additional properties then.